# How to come back to view controller?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

If I am using 5 view controllers in my application, and if I was on the 5th view controller, what code should I write if I want to come back to the 2nd view controller on a button action?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `UINavigationController`?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can do is `popToViewController`.

So there are several steps:

1. Get the UIViewController which you want to go back to.
2. Bring out all the view controllers from the navigation controller by doing something like `self.navigationController.viewControllers`.
3. Run a for each loop and add an if condition within for each to match the view controller you want to from step 1.
4. Use the `popToViewController` method of the navigation controller.

Something like as follows:

```
for (UIViewController *vc in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
    if ([vc isKindOfClass:[ViewController2 class]]) {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:vc animated:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: The 1st argument to `popToViewController` should be the variable `vc`.

Comment: No need for the loop or `if`. Just do `[self.navigationController popToViewController:self.navigationController.viewControllers[1] animated:YES];`. The `viewControllers` array will be in the order the view controllers are stacked.

Comment: @rmaddy Corrected the answer, thanks for pointing out. And yeah, i suggested him the for loop because he might know which controller class to go to but doenst know the index.